# Solunar theory of animal activity

Tags: behaviour

Solunar theory, which states that animal activity in wild (fishes, deer) depends on position of sun and moon in sky.

Based on the solunar calender, hunters seek for optimal time for hunting fishes.

I am wondering that how solunar calender is developed from the sun's and moon's rise/set timing or from their positions in sky? For instance if I know the position of sun and moon in sky how would one forecast the animal activity timings of that day? OR the solunar calender is based on some statistical forecasting?

Thanking you.

Comment: by observation!! all organisms have circadian rythm but their behaviors are different. some are diurnal while some are nocturnal

Comment: Right ! But my question is more mathematical. I am interested in how we derive the animal activity forecast from the sun/moon data ?

Comment: If there is a pattern based activity, you can mathematically model it and make extrapolations so as correctly mentioned above, you make observations, gather data and model it. What mathematical formulations people use I do not know but would be interesting if someone could point to a source. there is a similar version of your question here (http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=295970)

Comment: are you looking for the kind of charts that are provided on this website. http://www.solunarforecast.com/

Comment: No. The way they find the best day of the month.